# Extract data from Dictionary in IOS

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I'm parsing xml file and getting values in a dictionary, i have tried to extract the values by their name but some of it i'm getting and remaining is null. This is my dictionary,

```
dictionary: {
"__name" = QF;
"_category" = "C&M";
"_id" = AB2001;
"_ni_exempt" = no;
"_topic" = Alertness;
answers =     {
    answer =         (
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "give an arm signal as well as using your indicators";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "signal so that other drivers can slow down for you";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = yes;
            text = "look over your shoulder for a final check";
        },
                    {
            "_correct" = no;
            text = "select a higher gear than normal";
        }
    );
};
question =     {
    explanation =         {
        text = "If you want to make a U-turn, slow down and ensure that the road is clear in both directions. Make sure that the road is wide enough to carry out the manoeuvre safely.";
        voice =             {
            "_id" = "AB2001-2";
        };
    };
    prompt = "Mark one answer";
    text = "Before you make a U-turn in the road, you should";
    voice =         {
        "_id" = "AB2001-1";
    };
    xref = "DES s4, DES s9, HC r159-161";
};
}
```

This is the code i'm trying to extract the values,

```
-(void)fetchValuesFromDictioanry:(NSDictionary*)xmlDict
{

for (NSString *string in [xmlDict allKeys])
{
    if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:[xmlDict valueForKey:string]];
    }
    else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if ([string isEqualToString:@"_id"])
        {
            _lblID.text = [xmlDict valueForKey:@"_id"];
            NSLog(@"ZZZ %@",_lblID.text);

            _lblAlert.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"_topic"];
            NSLog(@"Make: %@ ",_lblAlert.text);

             _lblxref.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"xref"];
             NSLog(@"Make: %@ ",_lblxref.text);

            _lbltext.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"text"];
            NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lbltext.text);

            _lblgraphic.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"explanation"];
            NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblgraphic.text);

            _lblprompt.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"prompt"];
            NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblprompt.text);

            _lblvoice.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:@"_id"];
            NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lblvoice.text);
        }
       // NSLog(@"MMM: %@ ", [xmlDict valueForKey:string]);

        //Set here other labels
    }
    else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [xmlDict valueForKey:string]) {

            [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:dictionary];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now when i get values in the labels like in lblID and lblAlert it shows me the value but when i try to get inner values it shows me null like for lbltext or lblxref. How can i get the vales from inner dictionary?

Comment: The key `answers` in the outer dictionary is a dictionary with a single key `answer` whose value is an array of dictionaries, so you will need to access it in that way - first get the dictionary from `answers`, then get the array from the key `answer` in that dictionary, then iterate over the array to get each answer dictionary

Comment: can u guide me how can i get through the code?@Paulw11

Comment: not every key is in the root dictionary you'd like to extract, e.g. `prompt` or `explanation` is under the key `question`, but the `text` is at various places but definitely not in the root; have you considered that yet?

Comment: I have got explanation, prompt and text values but now i'm confuse at the correct and text tag under answer tag, how can i get this. @holex

Comment: @Nabeel, it'd be something like this: `... = [[[[rootDict objectForKey:@"answers"] objectForKey:@"answer"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];` and you should have the _"give an arm signal as well as using your indicators"_.

Comment: but how can we get other tag values with name _correct and text, they are four times in dictionary. @holex

Comment: @Nabeel, that'd be something like this: `... = [[[[rootDict objectForKey:@"answers"] objectForKey:@"answer"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"_correct"]` for the answer's text above. you question indicates me you are not familiar with working with _collections_ in ObjectiveC, you may need to [read this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary).

Comment: I got it thanks a lot make this ur answer . @holex

Answer (score 0):

replace function fetchValuesFromDictioanry with below

```
-(void)fetchValuesFromDictioanry:(NSDictionary*)xmlDict
{
    if ([xmlDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        for (NSString *string in [xmlDict allKeys])
        {
            if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            {
                [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:[xmlDict valueForKey:string]];
            }
            else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                if ([string isEqualToString:@"_id"])
                {
                    _lblID.text = [xmlDict valueForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"ZZZ %@",_lblID.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"_topic"])
                {
                    _lblAlert.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Make: %@ ",_lblAlert.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"xref"])
                {

                    _lblxref.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Make: %@ ",_lblxref.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"text"])
                {
                    _lbltext.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lbltext.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"explanation"])
                {
                    _lblgraphic.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblgraphic.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"prompt"])
                {
                    _lblprompt.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ",_lblprompt.text);
                }
                else if ([string isEqualToString:@"_id"])
                {
                    _lblvoice.text = [xmlDict objectForKey:string];
                    NSLog(@"Model: %@ ", _lblvoice.text);
                }

            }
            else if ([[xmlDict valueForKey:string] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                for (NSDictionary *dictionary in [xmlDict valueForKey:string]) {

                    [self fetchValuesFromDictioanry:dictionary];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not a dictionary")
    }

}
```

Comment: getting this error [__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000256830
2017-12-13 23:48:45.662669-0800 XML[2175:746546] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000256830' . @Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: how to get values from tags with same name? @Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: It is not catching the explanation if statement. @ Hitesh Sultaniya

Comment: @Nabeel is it printing "Not a dictionary" in log ? if yes the there is some problem in your dictionary i think

Comment: no its not printing Not a dictionary but showing null if i NSLog the value. @Hitesh Sultaniya